# How to create a view for settings of my iPhone apps in Xcode storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I am new in iOS programming and I would like to create I view for the settings of my app that looks like iPhone's one (like in the picture). Some of rows will call other views when taped and other will not.

What is the best way to do that? I thought about TableView with prototype cells, but is there a best way to do it? or a best-practice for what I want to do? Or maybe a tutorial online?

[image: Application's settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fast way in Interface Builder:

Use a UITableViewController, make it STATIC and use the GROUPED style (all in IB).

You can setup the cells to show disclosure indicators (or not) in IB also.

You can segue directly from the rows or the UITableViewController to where you want to go.

If you segue from the UITableViewController, implement the "didSelectRowForIndexPath" method and call "performSegueWithIdentifier" accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A structure like this is best by UITableView.
First you select how many sections you want, and customize each section with a data structure that you have to be filled with (Probably an array.)
Then you fill up each rows inside

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method, and call your value from the array/dictionary that you have.

for going to a next view when clicked upon 
Use the method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is using **static UITableViewCell**.

See [UITableView Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html).

Answer (score 0):

**The optimal solution here is undoubtedly `UITableView`.** This is because firstly, you have the need to display a list of options that would have external links to other pages and UITableView is designed and used for this purpose.

In an addition to that, if you want, you can also expand and collapse the rows of your parent TableView into a Child TableView i.e a UITableView as a subview of its parent `UITableView`.

Put up a `UITableView` and populate it with `UITableViewCell`. That will be just fine with the requirement you have.

Hope this helps.